# Refactoring code @staticmethod design

Tags: python, tornado

I have a tornado application that previously had the following structure:

```
class handler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def do_something(self,m):
      # do something

  def on_message(self,msg):
     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.do_something,m)
```

Unfortunately this approach is becoming too cumbersome as my application has increased in size. I need to split out the helper methods E.g. do_something() from the handler class. The solution I have thought about is the creating another class:

```
class SessionMsgHandlers(object):

   @staticmethod
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def do_something(ws,m):
      # do stuff
```

then calling this function like:

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(SessionMsgHandlers.do_something,self,m)
```

This will allow me to group my functions outside of the WebSocketHandler class however it will mean nearly all my functions will be static. The only real benefit of having them associated to a class is that i can group different handler functions together. From a design perspective would it be better to just have a standard module with functions rather than associate them to a specific class (that will never have an instance) that has static methods? Also is there much performance penalty in having these as static methods rather than normal functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract the methods in order to group them by common functionality, perhaps it might be the best to make your classes into mixins:

```
class SessionMsgMixin(object):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def do_something(ws,m):
       # do stuff


class MyHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler, SessionMsgMixin):

    def on_message(self,msg):
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.do_something,m)
```

Comment: Ah very clever! Thanks Berislav. Would the methods in Mixin classes still have access to the WebsocketHandler and methods of other Mixin classes assuming I use more than one Mixin?

Comment: Yes, the resulting class would inherit all of the classes used to construct it -- Python fully supports multiple inheritance.